# Cannot read the FCM message content from Swift

Tags: swift, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to read the userInfo object of UNNotificationResponse. I tried casting it to Dictionary. But it returns nil.

I printed the object.

```swift
let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
if let messageID = userInfo["taskDoc"] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
}
```

it prints following.

```swift
{"assigned_user":"+sddadad","assigned_user_image":"","assigned_user_name":"Chandima 68","assignee_comment":"","checklist":[],"created_at":{"_seconds":1559297826,"_nanoseconds":851644000},"created_by":"+94711555268","description":"","due_at":{"_seconds":1559297824,"_nanoseconds":745725000},"group_id":"I0W3Nrrr0IpUVaI33SnU","group_name":"Photo Group new","status":0,"title":"Ada","updated_at":{"_seconds":1559297826,"_nanoseconds":851644000}}
```

But when I try to cast the object it returns nil.

```swift
let task = userInfo["taskDoc"] as? Dictionary<String, Any>
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the values ​​of `userInfo["taskDoc"]` you can do it like that

```
let test = userInfo["taskDoc"] as? NSDictionary
```

If you wish to obtain the information of the notification you can do it in the following way

```
let title = response.notification.request.content.title
let subtitle = response.notification.request.content.subtitle
let body = response.notification.request.content.body
```